# validation in rails with two date attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

so i have a model with two date attributes

```
  # migration
  t.date :valid_from
  t.date :valid_until
```

these are optional and you should be able to define only `valid_from` or `valid_until`, but if both dates are filled i want (of course) that `valid_from` is earlier than `valid_until`.

the best place to check for this, is inside the model with a validator, isnt it? i think the controller would not be the best place for this.

how could this be done with a validator inside my model? i tried several things without luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a custom validator:

```
validate :valid_date_range_required

def valid_date_range_required
  if (valid_from && valid_until) && (valid_until < valid_from)
    errors.add(:valid_until, "must be later than valid_from")
  end
end
```

Comment: nice, while googling i didn't find an example with defining a simple method inside my object, they were all about subclassing the validator. works fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself having to validates a lot of dates, you might want to add the [date validator](https://github.com/codegram/date_validator) gem! It gives you a nice syntax and probably all the flexibility you need.